# grab the latest date record that is not later than date in another column SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, datetime, select, google-bigquery

I have two date columns in BQ table. `pageview_date` and `edited_date`, as well as `id` column. I need to output the data - row by row - and for each record I want to grab a value from `edited_date` column that is the latest date in that column BUT is not later than the `pageview_date` value itself. And if both dates are equal then leave it as is. It also has to correspond with the ids. Data looks like this:

```
id         pageview_date         edited_date
A            03/01/22               02/28/22
A            03/01/22               02/02/22
A            03/01/22               02/02/22
B            03/01/22               01/01/22
B            03/01/22               01/01/22
B            03/01/22               01/31/22
C            03/01/22               04/01/22
C            03/01/22               03/25/22
C            03/01/22               03/01/22
```

Desired output is:

```
id         pageview_date         edited_date
A            03/01/22               02/28/22
A            03/01/22               02/28/22
A            03/01/22               02/28/22
B            03/01/22               01/31/22
B            03/01/22               01/31/22
B            03/01/22               01/31/22
C            03/01/22               03/01/22
C            03/01/22               03/01/22
C            03/01/22               03/01/22
```

Comment: `BUT is not later than the pageview_date value itself.` - this rule is not presented in your sample! please add

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant You are right! I am very sorry. Added with id `C` in my example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is use the `MAX` window function in the `edited_date` column partitioned by the `id`:

```sql
with sample as (
  select 'a' as id, DATE('2022-03-01') as pageview_date, DATE('2022-02-28') as edited_date
  UNION ALL
  select 'a' as id, DATE('2022-03-01') as pageview_date, DATE('2022-03-28') as edited_date
  UNION ALL
  select 'a' as id, DATE('2022-03-01') as pageview_date, DATE('2022-01-28') as edited_date
)
SELECT
  id,
  pageview_date,
  MAX(IF(edited_date <= pageview_date, edited_date, null)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as new_edited_date
FROM sample
```

Note if there's no `edited_date` before an pageview_date, the `new_edited_date` will be `null`.

Comment: This works on the sample, however, when I applied it to the entire dataset I noticed that some of edited_date are later than pageview_date. This was easily fixed when I added `OVER (PARTITION BY id, pageview_date)` So thank you very much! I accepted your answer.